# C# HttpClient slow uploading speed

Tags: c#, .net, performance, google-drive-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to upload large (50 MB - 32 GB) files to Google.Drive. I'm using google-api-dotnet which provides upload logic and encryption support. The main problem is slow uploading speed.

I looked through api [source code](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/9c6c1930a4ac2e3a9ccd8655757a76b544442610/Src/GoogleApis/Apis/%5BMedia%5D/Upload/ResumableUpload.cs). Each file is uploaded by chunks (I set chunk size to 4 MB) Each chunk is uploaded via new HttpRequestMessage instance. HttpClient is created once the api service started and reused for all requests.

The upload speed is 600 kbytes/s and stable while my uplink is 10 times faster.

I captured traffic with Wireshark:
[image: slow-uploading-screenshot] 
Each chunk is divided into hundreds or thousands small TLS packets. And for each small TLS packed a confirmation is expected. So the resulting speed is very low.

But when I start Fiddler proxy, the speed becomes as fast as my uplink can do.
The TLS packets going very fast in parallel and the confirmations are received later:
[image: tls-packets-first-screenshot]
[image: tcp-ack-later]

I tried my code on 5 PC's with Win7 and all showed similar low uploading speed. But when I tried on Win10 PC - the speed was very good.
Also I tried Google.Drive client application and it had same problems with speed. 
I tried to search about this behaviour, but I didn't found anything.

1. Why are 4 MB chunks divided into 4 KB TLS packets? Can I increase TLS packets size?
2. How can I make the TLS packets sending in parallel as Fiddler does?
3. Or is there other methods of increasing upload speed?

Comment: I wonder if this is a variant of the problem described at https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/38768/slow-upload-speed-from-windows-stations-to-ssl-hosts which some software (Fiddler) is working around, but your use of HttpClient is not.

Comment: I would give a try to https://github.com/Redth/HttpTwo

Comment: I am facing same problem. Did you found any work around for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is highly possible that the problem is the google link, not anything else. I have been uploaded things to google drive with chrome and besides my upload link is giant (50mbps up), google seems limited.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum record size is 16kB for SSLv3/TLSv1 so maybe you handshake with older version. I think google is optimized to user SPDY / HTTP2 protocole that can send in parallel in the same connection. Maybe your client not...

[How to make the .net HttpClient use http 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685151/how-to-make-the-net-httpclient-use-http-2-0)