# HttpClient - Only HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 version requests are currently supported. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, dotnet-httpclient, http2

Recently I enabled HTTP/2 support on Azure for our Web API. Followed this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis

However when I try to do a HTTP/2 enabled request from our HttpClient I am getting following exception:

> Only HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 version requests are currently supported.
>   Parameter name: value

I have the latest System.Net.Http nuget package installed and setting the version on the request like this:

```
yourHttpRequestMessage.Version = new Version(2, 0);
```

I have no idea what is wrong here given that I followed the guide and used the latest System.Net.Http nuget package.

Note that the HttpClient is living in a .net standard library and is being used in a Xamarin application.

Comment: Is there any documentation stating that latest `System.Net.Http` supports 2.0

Comment: Check remarks here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks it looks like it is support on some platforms.

Comment: For windows you would need to change the handler to use [WinHttpHandler Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.winhttphandler?view=netcore-2.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: This looks promising https://stackoverflow.com/a/43101990/5233410