# Only HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 version requests are currently supported

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I trying to do a request to apns server with http2 request but i got this error message :

> Only HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 version requests are currently supported.\r\nParameter name: value

My request :

```
public static async Task<string> SendManualApns(int type, long? requestId, string title, string message, int badge, string deviceToken)
{
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ApnCertPath), ApnCertPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://api.sandbox.push.apple.com/3/device/" + deviceToken);
    req.Version = new Version(2, 0);
    req.Headers.Add("apns-topic", cert.Subject.Substring(cert.Subject.LastIndexOf('=') + 1));

    string sound = type == (short)NotificationType.RequestTechnicianNow ? "spaceBell.caf" : "default";
    string category = type == (short)NotificationType.RequestTechnicianNow ? "nowRequestCategory" : "none";
    req.Content = new StringContent("{\"aps\":{\"alert\":{\"title\":\"" + title + "\",\"body\":\"" + message + "\"},\"badge\":" + badge + ",\"sound\":\"" + sound + "\",\"requestId\":" + requestId + ",\"type\":" + type + ",\"category\":\"" + category + "\"}}");
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler { ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual };
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
    var response = await new HttpClient(handler).SendAsync(req);
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        return "APNS error " + response.StatusCode + ": " + content;

    return "success";
}
```

I using .netframework 4.7.2 in asp.net mvc webapi 2 project

I was using pushsharp but it stopped because it is not support http2 yet

Comment: Is error occurring in client or in the response from the server?

Comment: I think its in client

Comment: There are a lot of interesting comments/answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32685151/23354 - however, as with most things: the easiest answer is probably "update to .NET Core 3.1 or .NET 5" (or later)

Comment: i already upgraded to .net 4.7.2 and it support http2, i cant upgrade whole project to net core

Answer (score 3):

By default `HttpClient` uses `HTTP 1.1` as mentioned in [ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestversion?view=net-5.0)

you can try, following way to explicitly tell `client` `object` to use version 2

```
var client = new HttpClient()
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001"),
    DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0)
};
```

Alternatively, you can use Nuget Package `WinHttpHandler` and pass this `handler` to `client` object like,

```
var handler = new WinHttpHandler();
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

You can check the discussion around this [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31217#issuecomment-543868486)

Answer (score 0):

If using asp.net webform then install below package first

WinHttpHandler Nuget Package

and use the below code

```
var apnSettings = new ApnSettings
{
AppBundleIdentifier = "",
P8PrivateKey = "",
P8PrivateKeyId = "",
TeamId = "",
ServerType = ApnServerType.Development
};

var httpHandler = new WinHttpHandler();
var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler);
var apn = new ApnSender(apnSettings, httpClient);
var payload = new AppleNotification(Guid.NewGuid(), messageBody, "MyNotification");
var apnsResponse = Task.Run(() => apn.SendAsync(payload, deviceId)).Result;
```