# How to communicate with a gRPC API from a Blazor app using .NET Aspire?

Tags: c#, .net, grpc, dotnet-aspire

I'm currently experimenting with .NET Aspire. [According to docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/get-started/quickstart-build-your-first-aspire-app?tabs=dotnet-cli#:%7E:text=.NET%20Aspire%20is%20designed%20to%20streamline%20connections%20and%20configurations%20between%20these%20types%20of%20services.%20In%20this%20quickstart%2C%20you%20learn%20how%20to%20create%20a%20.NET%20Aspire%20Starter%20Application%20template%20solution.), Aspire is used to streamline connections and communication between services in applications. One of the features that Aspire offers is the ease of communications between services, by giving each a special name that can be resolved via them, removing the need to manually set the ports and match the addresses for making services connect.

In the [.NET Aspire Quickstart Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/get-started/quickstart-build-your-first-aspire-app?tabs=dotnet-cli), is it explained that you can set custom names to your projects in the `AppHost` Project's `Program.cs` file like this:

```cs
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder (args);

var usersApi = builder
    .AddProject<Projects.Bargeh_Users_API> ("usersapi"); // Setting the name "usersapi" to the project


builder.AddProject<Projects.Bargeh_Main_Wapp> ("bargehmainwapp")
    .WithReference (usersApi)
    .WithReference (smsApi)
    .WithLaunchProfile ("https");

builder.Build ().Run ();
```

Again from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/get-started/quickstart-build-your-first-aspire-app?tabs=dotnet-cli#:%7E:text=builder.Services.AddHttpClient%3CWeatherApiClient%3E(%0A%20%20%20%20static%20client%3D%3E%20client.BaseAddress%20%3D%20new(%22http%3A//apiservice%22))%3B), you can add this code in the project that wants to have access to the other service and let Aspire know that you need that service and resolve that URL for you:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<UsersApiHttpClientProvider>(
    static client=> client.BaseAddress = new("http://usersapi"));
```

Then, you can inject `UsersApiHttpClientProvider` wherever you want and make use of it.

This approach works, but only for accessing APIs that are open to normal HTTP requests. The problem is, that the `UsersApi` that I'm using is not a REST API, but it's a GRPC service. I can connect to the API and send requests to it, but I'm unable to send real GRPC requests.

My question is, how can I make my client projects (a Blazor Web App in this case) connect to my backend GRPC Services using `Grpc.Net` packages, while the connection between them is established by .NET Aspire?

Comment: A GRPC uses HTTP/2.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRPC and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685151/how-to-make-the-net-httpclient-use-http-2-0

Comment: @jdweng please check the update to the question's text

Comment: You want a relay where the frontend is a standard HTTP connection and the backend a HTTP/2 connection?

Comment: No @jdweng I just want to access that gRPC service from other projects via Grpc.Net and Grpc package for ASP.NET Core and using `GrpcChannel.ForAddress` method

Comment: How do you expect to connect to a HTTP/2 server?

Comment: Sorry @jdweng, but I don't understand what you mean. I'm just trying to connect to a gRPC service that its address is resolved by Aspire. There's no problem if I manually run both projects at the same time and assign the address to the service myself, but I want Aspire to set the address automatically. I hope it helps.

Comment: The backend is GRPC which is HTTP/2.  The frontend is HTTP.  So the server needs to be a relay that on front end client is HTTP and backend server connects to ASPIRE using HTTP/2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after 2 days of investigation, comparing with implementation of existing modules and a lot of attempts I guess I figured out how it should be done.

Code of AppHost for me looks like following:

```
using System.Net.Sockets;

var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var server = builder.AddProject<Projects.Server>("server");

var apiservice = builder.AddProject<Projects.AspireHost_ApiService>("apiservice")
    .WithReference(server);


builder.AddProject<Projects.AspireHost_Web>("webfrontend")
    .WithReference(apiservice);

builder.Build().Run();
```

Here `Projects.Server` is an application with Grpc server.

Now the trickiest part. After analyzing approaches MS uses for connecting other services like Sql Server I can conclude that they use different `*Annotation` classes that are able to to convert Resource (in my case Project reference) to real connection string, for example from launch settings or IP + port from running container or some static values.

The produced connection strings depending on annotation can be passedeither as connection strings or as `services__<registration name>__<index>` as Environment Variables.

Both can be read from `IConfiguration` as default app builders connect by default Environment Variables Configuration Source.

`.AddSqlServerContainer(...)` and `.AddSqlServerConnection(...)` produce for example produces connection strings with registered name.

`.WithReference(<project>)` produces service annotation. So you have to look to get the connection string like following

```
_configuration.GetValue<string>("services:service:1")
```

As alternative you can do binding using Option Pattern approach.
Already implemented client side code uses binding to some specific section to pick main set of settings and put them into Settings class, then manually resolve connection string using `.GetConnectionString()` method on `IConfiguration` class and then assign connection string to the Settings class.

So I conclude that Grpc channel and client should be constructed as

```
IConfiguration configuration = ???;
var conntectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>("services:service:1");
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(conntectionString );
var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
...
```

Factories or other mechanisms to do it as for your flavor.

IMPORTANT NOTE: For me `.WithReference()` produces TWO connection strings like:

```
services__server__0 http://_http.localhost:55224
services__server__1 http://localhost:55224
```

The first one is not consumable locally as cannot be resolved. The second one contains port that differs from the port I see in Aspire UI and from what you see in `launchSettings.json` but it actually works. I didn't get exactly why I have two urls yet but at least I can peak correct one manually or with skipping one starting with `http://_http`

In theory you can add your own annotation with `.WithAnotation()` after you add register project in `Host` or re-use existing annotation with the same method. That annotation might produce also connection string for example and you will be able consume the connection string.

I hope it helps you.

UPDATE:
It seems that two URL is intentional behavior and one of them is what they call "Named endpoint". See [named-endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/service-discovery/overview#named-endpoints)